# Задать значение в массиве один раз

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Как задать значение ключа в массиве только в первый раз. У меня программа - чат бот, и мне нужно задать каждому пользователю изначально, при первом сообщении "/start" значение 0.

К примеру пользователь "43943" набирает "\start" и массиву "a" даётся значение 0. a[43943] = 0. Но проблема в том что человек может набрать /start ещё раз, и тогда, к примеру, его "кошелек" сброситься на 0

Пример кода:

```py
def function():
    \\А тут мне нужно задать к примеру массиву "a" значение ключа 0 в 1284 ячейке "a[1284] = 0".\\
    print("Количество монет")
```

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, [ask]

Comment: Может лучше словарь использовать? А там оператором if проверять существует ли такой пользователь

Comment: Простой ответ - никак. Ответ посложнее - никак, но можно соорудить костыль. Правильный ответ: не надо делать массив со значениями для каждого пользователя, а надо сделать класс (например User) и для каждого пользователя создавать экземпляр класса.

Comment: либо проверять значение в этой ячейке через if not a[1284], либо поменять список на DefaultDict  из модуля collections встроенной библиотеки, либо как подметил @Эникейщик, создать класс пользователя и вообще все хранить в бд

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
def function():
    try:
        #Если элемент уже есть ничего не делаем
        a[43943]
    except:
        #Если нет, то вылетает исключение, здесь ловим его и устанавливаем значение '0'
        a[43943] = 0
```

Самый простой вариант

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)

Comment: Обычно не пишу такого, но это ужасный ответ!

Comment: Почему ужасный? Он мне помог и замечательно работает

Answer (score 1):

У вас неправильно выбрана структура данных. Для такой задачи лучше подойдёт [словарь](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Он и удобнее, и память использовать будет продуктивнее.

```
d = {}

def function():
    if 43943 in d:
        print("Количество монет " + str(d[43943]))
    else:
        d[43943] = 0
```

Или даже проще с использованием [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

def function():
    print("Количество монет " + str(d[43943]))
```

Если же вам по какой-то безумной причине нужно хранить эти данные именно в списках, то не стоит проверять наличие элемента в нём с помощью обработчика исключений. Элемент с индексом 43943 может быть в списке только в том случае, если в списке элементов больше, чем 43943. Поэтому проверить его наличие можно так:

```
if len(a) > 43943:
    # Элемент существует
```

Из этого же следует, что инициализировать элементы списка нулями можно и нужно там, где инициализируется сам список, а не в функции вызываемой пользователем.